# postman post req is not valid

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
require('dotenv').config();
const usersRoute = require('./routes/auth')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


app.use(bodyParser.json())

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB is Connected!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });


app.use('/',usersRoute)

app.listen('3500',()=>
console.log("our server is running")
)
```

when i try to the post request , i get this message :
Unexpected token a in JSON at position 51at JSON.parse

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

solved , stupid mistake
i forgot the "" in post request